# Is this grammatical? 'Having done the procedure allowed determining certain aspects of the problem in question'

Tags: gerunds, perfect-constructions

Is this grammatical? 'Having done the procedure allowed determining certain aspects of the problem in question'

Namely, can I use the perfect gerund here if what I mean is that only after the procedure is finished can you draw any conclusion about the problem being studied. Or does it sound way too complex and I should better rephrase it and simplify the sentence?

Thanks beforehand.

Comment: It's hard to say if it's grammatical, because it's not a complete sentence.  I could *maybe* see what it means, if it's part of a whole sentence, but it's definitely not clear.  Can you use it as part of a sentence?

Comment: Most people would probably say your text isn't grammatical because it features a ***dangling participle*** - we expect a valid "subject" to immediately follow the fronted clause  ***having** [done something]*.

Answer (score 3):

Your example is not grammatical.

It's clumsy and it struggles with a hanging/dangling participle/modifier.

That's to say that you don't tell us who did the procedure.

The phrase: **Having done the procedure** doesn't work as a subject.

You could rewrite it to read:

> Having done the procedure, we/they were able to determine....

where **we** becomes the subject, or

> Doing the procedure allowed us/them to determine....

where the phrase **Doing the procedure** becomes the subject, or

you could rephrase it completely

> We/they were able to determine certain aspects of the problem in question by doing the procedure.

Comment: "Having done the procedure allowed *for* determining certain aspects of the problem in question" would be OK, though definitely not the best phrasing to use.

Comment: @user3169 What you suggest is not a sentence. It contains neither a subject nor a verb.